# There is an error in that line --> `char ** tokenizer(char *line, int& noOfTokens) ` --- Can you help me?

Tags: c

There is an error in that line:

`char **tokenizer(char *line, int& noOfTokens)`
the error is -->`[Error] expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token`

```
char **tokenizer(char *line, int& noOfTokens) {
    char **tokens = (char **)malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
    char *token = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    int k = 0;
    token[0] = '\0';
    int i = 0;
    while (line[i] == ' ')
        i++;
    for (; line[i] != '\n' && line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == ',' || line[i] == '[' || line[i] == ']' || line[i] == '\t') {
            if (token[0]!='\0') {
                token[k] = '\0';
                tokens[noOfTokens++] = token;
                token = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
                token[0]='\0';
                k = 0;
            } else
                continue;
        } else {
            token[k++] = line[i];
        }
    }
    if (token[0] != '\0') {
        token[k] = '\0';
        tokens[noOfTokens++] = token;
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: This int& noOfTokens is not a valid parameter declaration in C.

Comment: There is no "reference" notation in C.

Comment: (Specifically, that is `C++`.)

Comment: @nih4t In any case your function is incorrect because it has a memory leak due to this statement token = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));. Consider for example string "A]".

Comment: @nih4t And using your approach the function should be declared like char ** tokenizer( const char * line, int * noOfTokens); or char ** tokenizer( const char * line, const char * delimiters, int * noOfTokens);

Comment: Your code seems to be duplicating much of the functionality of `strtok()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no passing by reference in C. You must pass the address of the number of tokens for the function to update it.'

You also have memory leaks and potential buffer overflows if a token has more than 9 bytes.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **tokenizer(const char *line, int *noOfTokens) {
    char **tokens = NULL;
    int i = 0;  // index into the string
    int k = 0;  // number of tokens
    int n;      // token length

    for (;;) {
        // skip whitespace
        while (line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\t')
            i++;
        // check for end of line
        if (line[i] == '\0' || line[i] == '\n')
            break;
        // test 1 byte tokens
        if (line[i] == ',' || line[i] == '[' || line[i] == ']') {
            n = 1;
        } else {
            // find token length
            n = strcspn(line + i, " \t\n,[]");
        }
        tokens = realloc(tokens, (k + 1) * sizeof(*tokens));
        tokens[k++] = strndup(line + i, n);
        i += n;
    }
    *noOfTokens = k;
    return tokens;
}
```